# Not snapping properly in edit mode

Tags: modeling, vertices, snapping

Recently I’ve been doing the donut tutorial by the blender guru. But when I try to make the icing, it goes through the dough part. It seems that only the vertices are snapping to the surface.I’ve tried everything I could find but I still can’t find a solution. Please help me with this.[image]

Comment: I've never done the tutorial (so I might not be as useful as others) but you might be snapping to the backface of the torus.  Does it help to turn on Backface Culling?

Comment: probably what's happening is that you are snapping the vertices of the icing mesh to the faces of the donut mesh, but the faces of the icing may penetrate into the faces of the donut, if you don't want that you need to create additional vertices in your icing mesh and make them snap as well

Comment: Are you snapping to the vertexes? Or the faces? Looks like the icing-mesh isn't large enough, or your snapping to the wrong part of the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I was able to fix it by adding vertices.